# Postgres archive_cleanup_command

Tags: postgresql

having a master/slave setup, that is in sync(streaming), I was wondering how to cleanup the wal/archives on the master (it is a postgres 15, but our backup tool cannot backup postgres v15 yet), so we create dumpfiles.  So, there is no mechanism from backup to cleanup the wal files.

### I tried setting this:
show archive_cleanup_command
;
archive_cleanup_command

pg_archivecleanup -d /data/postgres/archive %r >> /data/postgres/archive/cleanup.log

but it seems it should be on the slave? and also does nothing on the master, but there I don't have an issue with wal files, I need to clean them on the master!

I can clean them manually of course with the almost same command, or even automate that, but I'm not sure if that is the correct way to do?

other solution, or a clear explanation (I can't find any clear info about this).

thanks

Comment: pg_archivecleanup is obsolete.  With slots you don't need an archive to support streaming.  If you don't have an archive, you don't need to clean it up.   If you need an archive to support something other than streaming, pg_archivecleanup is unlikely to help with that anyway.